# How to create an array with size that is passed through the textbox?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

How to create an array with size that is passed through the textbox?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8nSH.png)

```
int massivSize = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
int odnMassiv = new int[massivSize];
```

Comment: Variable `odnMassiv` is declared as a simple `int`. You can't assign an array to it. Use `int[] odnMassiv = new int[massivSize];` or simply `var odnMassiv = new int[massivSize];`. Both are equivalent

Comment: @Flydog57
Thanks. You have helped me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use int[] or var in declaration, like this:

```
int massivSize = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
var odnMassiv = new int[massivSize];
```

or

```
int massivSize = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
int[] odnMassiv = new int[massivSize];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typed:.
`int odnMassive = ...`

While it should be:.
`int[] odnMassive =`.

Or you can use *var* instead, like:
`var odnMassive = new int[massiveSize];`
I find this more useful in most cases (except when the data type is unknown)